# storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController returns the wrong uiViewController

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have this code in swift.

The code is supposed to load tutorial page for first comers and then navigate to `MainStoryboard`.

This `if (controller is InlineMainViewController ){` used to return true but now it returns alwyas false

what can cause the main story board not to show? 
or to load different `viewController`?

I have check in the identity hierarchy that the storyboard is connected to `InlineMainViewController` uiViewController.

what else should I check?

```
  func chooseAndLuanchStoryboard(){
        Settings.registerDefaults()

        if( !Settings.groupDefaults().boolForKey(onboardingKey)) {
            launchStoryboard(Storyboard.OnboardingTofu)
        } else {
            launchStoryboard(Storyboard.Main)
        }
    }



func launchStoryboard(storyboard: Storyboard) {
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarHidden(true, withAnimation: .Slide)
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboard.rawValue, bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()!
    if (controller is InlineMainViewController ){
        mainViewController = controller as! InlineMainViewController
    }
    window?.rootViewController = controller
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify within your storyboard that the initial VC is , in fact, your  InlineMainViewController. If your VC is embedded in a UINavigationController or UITabBarController, then it is possible that the initial VC is actually one of those classes or a subclass. 
Your Storyboard Enum, could you share the code? Is the type of raw value for each case String?

I would add this as a comment, but my account is too new.

Comment: The problem happens only why I add this attribute: `@objc(ViewController)  // match the ObjC symbol name inside Storyboard
public class InlineMainViewController: UIViewController, `

Comment: The (ViewController) after your @objc modifier tells objective-C what name to look for when it looks for that code, so it could be related to your issue.  Also related, your Enum with string raw value cannot be seen by objective C.

Comment: but it doesn't work even if i write "Main" instead of "storyboard.rawvalue"

Comment: Why do you assign both the window's rootVc and your property mainViewController the controller? Is it possible that you want to assign the mainViewController to the window.rootViewController ? The name after @objc(ViewController) means that objective-C will use that as a class name, not a string identifier. Can you remove the @objc? Are you in a mixed language project?

Comment: You should update your code to this.

`if let controller = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? InlineMainViewController  {
    window?.rootViewController = controller
} else {
 fatalError(“Couldn’t load the required controller”)
}`